# Connected components of Lorentz Group $O_1(3)$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let us consider the set of all vector isometries of the space $\mathbb{E}^3_1$, $O(1,3)$. I know this group has four connected components but I can't prove it. Could someone help me? I'm completely stuck...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See section $1.1$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group). $O(1,3)$ is the Lorentz group.

Comment: There are only intuitions, not formal proofs... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lorentz group has four disconnected, disjoint components according to the signs of the determinant $\det(\Lambda)=\pm 1$ and the sign of $\Lambda_{00}$. For a proof (and the notations) see *Proposition $I.2.$* in Arthur Jaffe's notes on [Lorentz transformations, rotations and boosts](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFAQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fisites.harvard.edu%2Ffs%2Fdocs%2Ficb.topic1466080.files%2FRotations-Lorentz-Transformations.pdf&ei=Ohq-VO_6HcPsO6bFgeAO&usg=AFQjCNG2NavM3PaWOzCX_WqdZUbiHSKr9g&bvm=bv.83829542,d.ZWU) of $2013$.

Comment: That link is broken. [This](http://home.ku.edu.tr/~amostafazadeh/phys517_518/phys517_2016f/Handouts/A_Jaffi_Lorentz_Group.pdf) appears to be an updated link.  One mighgt also note directly in the answer: "*As det Λ is a polynomial in the matrix elements Λij , it depends continuously on these matrix elements. Hence L has disconnected components according to the sign of det.*"

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Thank you for your help!

Comment: My pleasure. From the ["guest mathematician" answer](https://twitter.com/GWOMaths/status/1313004647636967425) to yesterday's Math Calendar question on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

From the ["Volunteer Guest Mathematician" answer](https://twitter.com/GWOMaths/status/1313004647636967425) to yesterday's (October 4, 2020) Daily math Challenge Calendar on the same question:

[image]
[image]